# What is the syntax to perform a custom test after a promise is fulfilled with should.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, should.js

I am trying to express something like the following:

```
it("should use the 'text' mode", () => {
    let usedMockMode = false;

    let env = new Environment();
    let mockMode = { parse: () => usedMockMode = true };
    env.modes.set("text", mockMode);

    return env.parseContent("foo", "text")
        .should.eventually.be.true(() => usedMockMode);
                       // ^--------------------------^
                       //        Pseudo-code
})
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What ist your testing framework (aka where does your `it` come from)? mocha? Jasmine? something else? Most of them support an parameter to the function starting in your first line.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ: that's an assertion framework.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I am using the mocha.js testing framework and in some cases I'm using the 'mocha-testdata' module which allows me to pass data for many test iterations through the arguments of my `it` test function.

Comment: Have you tried using [match](https://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-match)? `.should.eventually.match(() => usedMockMode)`

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial-and-error I eventually found that the following works:

```
it("should use the 'text' mode", () => {
    let usedMockMode = false;

    let env = new Environment();
    let mockMode = { parse: () => usedMockMode = true };
    env.modes.set("text", mockMode);

    return env.parseContent("foo", "text")
        .then(() => {
            usedMockMode.should.be.true();
        });
})
```

This didn't seem very intuitive to me since there is obviously some magic behind the scenes to bind the assertion to the context of the test.

Comment: You are using normal promise syntax. it has nothing to do with the assertion. With `.then` you are creating a new promise that gets executed _after_ the `parseContent` promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a new node and mocha at hand. but it should work with arrows as well.

```
describe('promise fn', function(){
  it('should fullfill a promise', function(done){
    …
    return env.parseContent('foo', 'bar').then(function(){
      (usedMockMode).should.be.true})
      .finally(done);
  });
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. The test hangs for 2000ms and then it throws a timed out error specifying that the `done` callback should have been invoked by the test. Even if I just invoke `done();` directly after the assertion; it still hangs. Even when I remove the `return` keyword from the promise. I am probably making a silly mistake... but it certainly wasn't working for me :/